# C# To Generate Word Document

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word, find

So I have a friend who is helping me and I'm really not a programmer but I can understand things when I have a template to build from.

I'm trying to create a program that accepts input from the user to generate a report for traffic accidents. Just to get started I was going to try and learn as much as I could to create the notification section which requires very little input and has little variance.

Section in CAPS would be the input requested from the user. It would be used in other areas so it should be stored as a string for other sections. Also, later there will be areas where the user has to enter parties, witnesses, and vehicles. Since there could be any number of combinations of the three it would have to be programmatically generated where as the notification could be find and replace.

Can someone point me in the right direction with an example code for just the following:

> NOTIFICATION: On DATE_DISPATCHED, at approximately TIME_DISPATCHED
>   hours, I was dispatched to LOCATION_DISPATCHED at COLLEGE for a report
>   of a CALL_TYPE
>
> NOTIFICATION: On 01-01-2000, at approximately 1000
>   hours, I was dispatched to South Lot at 1010 Address St for a report
>   of a small narrative about what happened.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but simply It's not working like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOCX has the function I needed and I was able to get this almost completely fixed. I have a working version of exactly what I need but I am now having other problems with the output format. I would suggest anyone with the same goal as I had here to study using a builder to transfer variables in textboxes to a DOCx argument string which is well documented on the DOCX webpage. https://docx.codeplex.com/discussions

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to assemble a word document based on a template and some user's input. I think [HotDocs](http://www.hotdocs.com/) is what you need.

If you want to assemble a document programmatically you may refer to Word Add-ins or Office App from Microsoft. Or [OpenXML Power Tools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) for more flexibility.

Comment: I have seen HotDocs and yes it is close to what I need but since I enjoy learning new things I have choosen the C# route. I also don't want to pay a subscription fee. Thanks for the other program suggestions.